# What is the purpose of the short cursor in command mode?

Tags: cursor, operator-pending-mode

If I'm in command mode with default vim and I press the right angle key, the cursor switches from the normal block to a short version. What is the function of this? (Sometimes it seems related to indent.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angled brackets `<` and `>` are the shift commands.

The reason it's a short block is that vim enters *operator-pending-mode*, and is waiting for you to complete the command. `>>` is used to shift the current line by one `shiftwidth` right, and `<<` is used to shift the current line one `shiftwidth` left. The brackets can also be followed by a motion command to shift multiple lines or blocks.

From vim's help file:

> operator-pending-mode *is like normal mode, but after an operator command has started, and Vim is waiting for a {motion} to specify the text that the operator will work on.*

For more information, read `:help shift-left-right` and the Vim wiki page on [shifting blocks visually](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Shifting_blocks_visually).

Comment: Operator-pending mode may be worth mentioning

Comment: @D.BenKnoble done.